# 15 pin COM Header on motherboard

Tags: motherboard, serial-port, pin

On a Lenovo M81 motherboard there is a 15 pin header labelled "COM2".

[image: 15 pin header]

I know that some serial interfaces can have 15 pins, but thought the most modern variation is 9 pin. I would have expected a 9 pin header on a fairly modern Core i5 PC. I can't find any 15 pin adapters that would convert this into a D-SUB 15 pin serial port.

What perplexes me further is that another, much older Lenovo 9702-7LG has a 9 pin header in the same place. This is also labelled COM2.

[image: 9 pin header]

Why 15 pins?

And if I were to buy something like this: [https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-16-Inch-Serial-Bracket-Header/dp/B007UQZD9K](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007UQZD9K)
how would I connect this to the 15 pin header? Would I simply plug it into the right-most pins?

Comment: The [Lenov0 manual](https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/thinkcentre_pdf/0a74545.pdf) indicates that a special cable assembly (which includes an active level shifter chip) is required.  If you have a voltmeter (e.g. DMM), then you can confirm this.  BTW even if there was a 9-pin header, there are two common pinouts in use on motherboards.  IOW there is no single standard for mobo pinout for COM ports.

Comment: See the second part of [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/627922/how-to-wire-the-lpt-and-com-port-headers-on-a-motherboard/627927#627927) for the two conventions for 9-pin mobo headers.

Comment: Thank you! Lenovo part number 71Y6217. I've also just realised that the older header is actually 11 pins, not 9, so that's some arbitrary Lenovo thing too.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly the 15pin port is "game port", not true serial port. Thus you can't convert it the way you are thinking.

Sometime I have seen them called "COM2" but that is a mistake on the board manufcaturer's side.

The correct cable and external port is this:

[image]

Comment: This wouldn't work in this situation. Lenovo are using their own bespoke header so you must purchase the part from them. Not cheap either! A new one is over £100 on some sites.

Comment: OK, good to know, thanks for the update. All my PCs are using generic MBs like Asus so this was a blind shot....