# Adding RS232(Serial Port) to motherboard

Tags: usb, motherboard, rs232

I need to add a RS232(Serial Port) connection to my pc, and unfortunately I'm unable to use RS232 to USB adapter, only direct RS232 connection, I have seen this item: [https://www.aliexpress.com/item/MYLB-DB9-RS232-to-10-pin-Ribbon-Cable-Connector-Adapter/32735919280.html?](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/MYLB-DB9-RS232-to-10-pin-Ribbon-Cable-Connector-Adapter/32735919280.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.2.726d6d354gPzge&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4_10065_10068_5015512_10059_5016212_10696_100031_10084_10083_5016313_10103_451_452_10618_10307_5015613,searchweb201603_45,ppcSwitch_5&algo_expid=73b6ce48-3a58-4554-ac33-7eea0b33bb05-0&algo_pvid=73b6ce48-3a58-4554-ac33-7eea0b33bb05&priceBeautifyAB=0)
and that seems nice, but I have no idea how to connect something like that, I'm pretty sure that it shouldn't be connected through the PSU, as I don't recall seeing anything similar from a PSU, so I assume you need to connect it directly to the motherboard somehow, which I believe is correct, but still, I don't know how to connect it to the motherboard, and if I even can, here are pictures of my motherboard:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tn2ju.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAMg6.jpg

My motherboard is MSI B75MA-E33, so Im not even sure its the correct place to ask, but hopefully someone can help me here, thanks! :)

Comment: The specifications say it has one Serial port connector. Check your manual to locate it.

Comment: You are correct, if Im not mistaken, according to the manual it is JCOM1 port, thank you :)

Comment: Beware, there are two common ways of wiring a motherboard 9-pin header to a DB9 connector.  Actually there's only one correct/sensible way (i.e. that's compatible with flat ribbon cable); the other way is a mistake that has propagated because of the manufactured quantity.  See https://superuser.com/questions/627922/how-to-wire-the-lpt-and-com-port-headers-on-a-motherboard

Answer (score 0):

Use any of these: https://www.google.com/search?q=pcie+rs232+card&tbm=shop
‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌

Comment: Thanks but people already answered it long ago :o